# Should I use different mutexes for different objects?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I am new to threading . Correct me if I am wrong that mutex locks the access to a shared data structure so that it cannot be used by other threads until it is unlocked . So, lets consider that there are 2 or more shared data structures . So , should I make different mutex objects for different data structures ? If no ,then how `std::mutex` will know which object it should lock ? What If  I have to lock more than 1 objects at the same time ?

Comment: A `std::mutex` does *not* lock any data structures by itself. Read up on what a mutex is and see the docs for `std::mutex`.

Comment: There have been systems (The Python interpreter for instance, IIRC) which used a single Global Lock for _every_ shared resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several points in your question that can be made more precise. Perhaps clearing this will solve things for you.

To begin with, a `mutex`, by itself, does not lock access to anything. It is  basically something that your code can lock and unlock, and some "magic" ensures that only one thread can lock it at a time.

If, **by convention**, you decide that any code accessing some data structure `foo` will first begin by locking a mutex `foo_mutex`, then it will have the effect of protecting this data structure.

So, having said that, regarding your questions:

- It depends on whether the two data structures need to be accessed together or not (e.g., can updating one without the other leave the system in an inconsistent state). If so, you should lock them with a single mutex. If not, you can improve parallelism by using two.
- The mutex does not lock anything. It is you who decide by convention whether you can access 1, 2, or a million data structures, while holding it.

Answer (score 2):

If you ***always*** needs to access both structures then it could be considered as a single resource so only a single lock is needed.

If you sometimes, even just once, need to access one of the structures independently then they can no longer be considered a single resource and you might need two locks. Of course, a single lock could still be sufficient, but then that lock would lock both resources at once, prohibiting other threads from accessing any of the structures.

Comment: In fact, you rarely really *need* more than one lock for correct execution. Of course, using more locks allows to exploit concurrency better

Comment: @HannoBinder Yeah, just added a sentence about that.

Answer (score 1):

Mutex does not "know" anything other than about itself. The lock is performed on mutex itself.

If there are two objects (or pieces of code) that need synchronized access (but can be accessed at the same time) then you have the liberty to use just one mutex for both or one for each. If you use one mutex they will not be accessed at the same time from two different threads.

If it cannot happen that access to one object is required while accessing the other object then you can use two mutexes, one for each. But if it can happen that one object must be accessed while the thread already holds another mutex then care must be taken that code never can reach a deadlock, where two threads hold one mutex each, and both at the same time wait that the other mutex is released.